# Hibernate Batch Save Performance

Tags: hibernate, memory-leaks, full-text-search

I use hibernate batch save processing for large amount of my domain entities.
First, when I had only single entity for insert in DB I didn't have problems with performance. But than I had added one-to-one relationship to another entity and after that I had problems with performance and memory leaks. Hibernate now did two insert at a time.

Here my domain model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "UPC" }) })
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", columnDefinition = "bigint")
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_ID_IDX")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "UPC")
    private String upc;

    @Column(name = "CURRENCY")
    private String currency;

    @Column(name = "RETAIL_PRICE")
    private Double retailPrice;

    @Column(name = "SALE_PRICE")
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_PRICE_IDX")
    private Double salePrice;

    @Type(type = "true_false")
    @Column(name = "INSTOCK")
    private boolean instock;

    @Column(name = "SHIPPING")
    private Double shipping;

    @Column(name = "RATING")
    private Integer rating;

    @Column(name = "VIEWS")
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_VIEWS_IDX")
    private Long views;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_ID_REVIEW_IDX")
    private List<ProductReview> reviews = new ArrayList<ProductReview>();

    //Here is new relation
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ProductInformation information;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", nullable = true)
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_CAT_IDX")
    private ProductCategory category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", nullable = true)
    @Index(name = "PRODUCT_BRAND_IDX")
    private ProductBrand brand;
```

ProductInformation entity:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_INFO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ProductInformation {

    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", columnDefinition = "integer", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "BUY_URL")
    private String buyUrl;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE_URL")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 10000)
    @Fields({
        @Field(index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.TOKENIZED, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer.class)),
        @Field(name = "name", index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.TOKENIZED, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = LowercaseKeywordAnalyzer.class)) })
    @Index(name = "product_info_name_idx")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LONG_DESCRIPTION", length = 10000)
    private String longDescription;

    @Column(name = "SHORT_DESCRIPTION", length = 10000)
    private String shortDescription;

    @Column(name = "KEYWORDS", length = 10000)
    private String keywords;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Product product;
```

How I setup my product:

```
result.setInformation(info);
    info.setProduct(result);
```

My DAO method:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int batchSave(List<Product> products, int batchSize) {

        int insertedCount = 0;
        Session batchSession = null;
        Transaction batchTransaction = null;
        try {
            batchSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            batchTransaction = batchStateLessSession.beginTransaction();
            for (Product product : products) {
                //First I used save() but this method calls select before insert and this                    //not a good idea.
                //batchSession.save(product);
                batchSession.persist(product);
                if (++insertedCount % batchSize == 0) {
                    batchSession.flush();
                    batchSession.clear();
                }
            }
            batchSession.flush();
            batchSession.clear();
            batchTransaction.commit();
            batchSession.close();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            if (batchSession != null && batchTransaction != null) {
                batchSession.clear();
                batchTransaction.commit();
                batchSession.close();
            }
        }

        return insertedCount;
    }
```

My batch size is 50 rows. All hibernate properties are setup correctly.
I don't use StatelessSession because I need create fulltext search indexes on my entity.
I have memory leak after save 30K entites. But my XML file has 10M entries.
When I didn't have ProductInformation entity and all fields were stored in Product entity, all worked perfectly without any leaks.

Have you any idea about my problem?
Maybe I should use StatelessSession and after insertion all rows create fulltext indexes on 10M rows table?

Comment: What database are you using? Is there a script language besides your SQL? Replace the 'batch' tag with the database you're using and it *might* be a start to getting the right people to see this. Your question could also really use better wording and formatting.